# Long-Lived Access Token?

Tags: rest-api

I [asked this question in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313612/salesforce-immortal-access-token) but was refered to go here.

I am trying to integrate Salesforce REST api into the contact form on our website.

Basically, whenever a person submits a contact form, a record in salesforce is created. I got it work but only with the token obtained via login request.

As sending two requests to handle a contact form is too much, I am looking for something long-lived that I can put directly to the code as static value. Does Salesforce support this kind of access token?

Comment: It looks like you already got an answer there...were you looking for anything more detailed?

Comment: Defacto standard (IMHO) article on this here if you need understanding on the process: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com